# How to get range of cells for Excel out of for loop

Tags: c#, excel

I am trying to get the values specified in the for loop, and then use them as the range of cells to get from Excel.  What is going wrong here?

```
List<string> str = new List<string>();

        // The follwing increments by 4, and starts at 25

        for (int i = 25; i <= lastRow; i += 4) // += means a + b
        {
            str = ws.Range["B"+i].Value;
         }
```

...

```
 SeriesCollection seriesCollection_mySeries = xlChart.SeriesCollection();
 Series series1 = seriesCollection_mySeries.NewSeries();

 series1.Values = str
```

;

Comment: is the value of ws a `list`?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what your question is? I do not understand what your trying to accomplish

Answer (score 0):

I think your question should be clarified, but this might help:

```
for (int i = 25; i <= lastRow; i += 4) // += means a + b
{
    string cellName = "B" + i.ToString();
    string cellValue = (string)ws.Range[cellName].Value;
    str.Add(cellValue);
}
```